# Feedback on elementary proof of evenness

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I'm aware of several approaches to proving that for natural numbers if $n^2$ is even then $n$ must be even. I would appreciate some feedback on my attempt using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. Is the proof correct? Can it be improved in any way?

To prove: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n^2$ is even $\implies$ n is even.

From the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, we have

$$1 \lt n^2 = p_1^2p_2^2\dots$$ for some primes $p_i$.

If $n^2$ is even, then $p_{1} = 2$. Thus, taking the square root, we have

$$n = 2p_2p_3...$$

Since this is a multiple of $2$, we can conclude that $n$ is even. $\blacksquare$

Comment: This is overkill. It is much easier to conclude that if $n=2k+1$ is not even, then also $n^2=4k^2+4k+1$ is not even. Done.

Comment: Did you mean $1 < n^2 = p_1^2.p_2^2...$ ?

Comment: Sure, but I'm focusing on my proof technique in terms of presentation, thoroughness, correctness etc. more than necessarily using the best approach.

Comment: Thanks @J.W.Tanner

Comment: @Robin Yes, I understand. Since you were asking "Can it be improved in any way?" My answer would be: yes, don't use the fundamental theorem at all. This is shorter and better. Mathematics is also about this exactly, and not about insisting on doing some fixed idea perfect.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with @Dietrich on this one. This holds true in several domains that don't have unique factorization at all, e.g., $\mathcal O_{\textbf Q(\sqrt{85})}$, $\mathcal O_{\textbf Q(\sqrt{165})}$, $\mathcal O_{\textbf Q(\sqrt{205})}$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct in structure, but there is one line where the detail is not fully correct.  For example, the step where you say $n^2 > 1 = p_{1}^{2}p_{2}^{2}..$ for some primes $p$. This should be broken down like:

1) Since $n^2$ is even, it is divisible by 2.  Namely $n^2 > 1$

2) Using fundamental theorem of arithmetic, $n$ has a prime factorization $n = p_{1}^{k_1}...p_{m}^{k_m}$ for $k_i \geq 1$, $p_i$ primes.  Thus $n^2$ has prime factorization $n^2 = p_{1}^{2k_1}...p_{m}^{2k_m}$

From there, the rest of your argument can be applied (without loss of generality, $p_1 = 2$, etc etc..)

Comment: Now a strange thing about this that is bothering me, is that by constructing n^2 from n, it seems more like we are proving the converse, or at least some statement about n, whereas the proof is meant to be about n^2. I don't doubt your proof is correct, but can you see my point?

Comment: I see your point, but the fact that $n$ has a prime factorization has to appear eventually (it appeared in your proof too).  Notice the real result starts when we say "One of the prime factors of $n^2$ must be $2$".  Then when we take the square root, out pops the fact that $n$ had to have a $2$ as well.  In other words, we assume nothing about $n$ other than the fact that the prime factorization of $n^2$ must be the square of primes in that of $n$.  Hope this helps